# How to delete Installed packages using ANT?

Tags: managed-package, ant, package, migration-tool, unmanaged-package

I'm trying to uninstall/delete packages from my salesforce org using ANT (Since there are lot of dependencies) how can I achieve this?

When I run ant undeployCode or undeploypackage it shows "successful" but the package is still there how come?

Package.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
 <version>37.0</version>
</Package>
```

destructivechanges.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
<fullName>package name</fullName>
 <types>
    <members>package name</members>
    <name>Package</name>
 </types>
```

build.xml

```
<target name="undeploypackage">
 <sf:deploy username="${sf.username}" password="${sf.password}"    sessionId="${sf.sessionId}" serverurl="${sf.serverurl}" singlepackage="true" deployroot="removecodepkg"/>
</target>
<target name="undeployCode">
  <sf:deploy username="${sf.username}" password="${sf.password}" sessionId="${sf.sessionId}" serverurl="${sf.serverurl}" maxPoll="${sf.maxPoll}" deployRoot="removecodepkg"/>
</target>
```

Comment: Does a manual uninstall also fail? Its very common for package uninstalls to fail because local code/components have been added that depend on the managed package and that blocks the uninstall. That code/components need to be removed first. Worth eliminated that problem first if it exists.

Comment: Yes it does, and I have many Installed packages that have lot of dependencies, the only thing I don't understand is that from command line it shows "successful"  while it isn't.

Comment: Yeah that isn't good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got It! What I did was uninstalled unmanaged package manually (Since Uninstalling/Removing it VIA desctructiveChanges.xml needs NameSpace to do so which an unmanaged package doesn't have one)

AND for Managed Package this is what I did

**Removed all the dependencies VIA ANT first** and then....

```
    <types>
        <members>NAMESPACE</members>
        <name>InstalledPackage</name>
   </types>
```

This worked well!